# Change color of word inside text box in Sketch

Tags: color, sketch-app

I want to change the text color of 1 line of text inside my textbox that has multiple lines of text. When I try to do this through the style dialog, the text color changes of the whole textbox content.

[image]

Strangely it is possible to style a single line with bold or an underline.

How do I change the color of just a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used **Fills Style** which effects on all of your layers. Remove the fills style and try to change the line color by changing the color of your font style.

[image]

Comment: No idea that white square represented color, thanks!